# Insert HTML element into CKEditor 4 at a specific location

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm having a little difficulty finding a way to insert data programmatically into my ckeditor instance.

An example of what i'm trying to accomplish:

```
<html>
  <body>
  <div id="top-area"></div>
  <div id="mid-area"></div> 
  <div id="bottom-area"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

On a button click I am trying to add data inside of the div with id mid-area.  I would even be okay with replacing that div with the data I have.

When I use

```
.insertHtml(
        '<div>This is a test insert for a random area</div>',
    );
```

It just populates that div at the very top.

I have tried targeting the div with

```
document.getElementById('mid-area')
```

but even that doesnt return any value.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since I am using the ckeditor4-angular package I am able to find the element and set the html by doing

```
@ViewChild('editor', { static: false }) component;

const element = this.component.instance.document.getById('mid-area');
element.setHtml('<div>This is a test insert for a random area</div>');
```

I will not mark this as the answer incase somebody else comes up with another solution that works better.  Thanks!